# time factor of heat increase (specific heat)

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

It takes 4 joules to bring 1 gram of water up 1 degree, but for how much time - 1 second? If not, how much and how to calculate it?

Comment: The time depends on what process you use to heat the water.  If you put the water on a very hot stove, the heat transfer will occur much faster than if you just leave it outside on a hot day.

Comment: It will always take 4 Joules of energy, but different processes can change the rate at which those 4 Joules are actually transferred into the system.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments we do not have enough information from just the energy required to heat to find out how long it takes.

The simple answer is that we need to look at the power of the heater.

Power is energy divided by time - or ammount of energy per time, which has units of $J / s$, which is Joule's per second. We normally write the unit as $W$, watts. $1 W = 1 J/s$.

So to answer your question if we had a $4$ Watt heater it would deliver $4$ Joules in $1$ second and heat the $1g$ of water. If we had a $2$ Watt heater it would take $2$ seconds to head $1g$ of water.

Comment: What if we had a 810nm 1000mw (1w) InfraRed laser focused on a 100 grams block of led? The specific heat of lead is 0.13 joules per gram. So that would mean it takes 100grams x 0.13 x100 = 1300 joules the block would heat up to 100 C if the starting temperature of the lead was 0 C? 1300 seconds?

Comment: @Александър - this sounds correct provided that the following 3 coniditions are true: 1) the lead (Pb) absorbs 100 % of the laser power, 2) the lead is heated the same everywhere and 3) the lead does not lose any heat whilst it is being heater. - What would happen in reality will depend on how correct these three assumptions are.